# Encountering Permission Denied Error When Reading JSON File from External Storage in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am developing a Flutter application and encountering a permission issue when trying to load a JSON file stored in a shared external folder. Interestingly, I can successfully save files to this folder but cannot load them.

Issue Description:
I am using the `dart:io` package to load a JSON file from a shared external directory (`/storage/emulated/0/Documents`). While the file saving process works fine, loading the file throws a permission error.

Error Message:
`PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myfile.json' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)`

Attempted Solutions:

1. I've ensured that both `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions are declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. I've ensured that 'android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"'

Questions:

1. Is there a way to load JSON files from a shared external folder without encountering permission issues?
2. Why am I able to save files to this folder but not load them?

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'flutter_log.dart';

Future<void> loadConfig() async {

  try {
    File jsonFile = await File(
        '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/myfile.json');


    var jsonData = json.decode(jsonFile.readAsStringSync());

    writeLog(jsonData);
  }
  catch (e){
    writeLog('Error: $e');
  }
}
```

Comment: Did your app create the file it cannot read?

Comment: It is a short json file that acts as a config and is readable. I confirmed that the path was read when installed inside the project.

Comment: You did not answer my question. I repeat: Did your app create that file? If not: Who created it?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer. This is not a json file created by me, nor is it a json file created by my app. This is a json file previously used in another program created by the same team.

Comment: So it is not created by your app. Then your app will not have read access on Android 11+ devices. Check with jsonFile.exists() and jsonFile.canRead() before trying to .. read.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tested it, but it keeps saying it can't be read. So can I read content I created myself on the app? Of course, if you create it yourself, it's not much different from storing and reading it from internal storage. I'll change the way to read. Thank you for the good answer.